# If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, show that $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}{(f(x_0 + ah) - f(x_0)) \over h }= af'(x_0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

**If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $a\in \mathbb R$, show that $ \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} {f(x_0 + ah) - f(x_0) \over h} = af'(x_0)$**

**EDIT** Suppose $u = ah $ then $ h = a/u$. So now we have $$ \lim_{u/a\rightarrow 0} {f(x_0 + u) - f(x_0) \over u/a}= \lim_{u/a \rightarrow 0} a{f(x_0 + u) - f(x_0) \over u}= a\lim_{u/a \rightarrow 0} {f(x_0 + u) - f(x_0) \over u} $$

Since  $ \lim\limits_{u/a \rightarrow 0} {f(x_0 + u) - f(x_0) \over u} = \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0} {f(x) - f(x_0) \over x-x_0}$. Then 
$a \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0} {f(x) - f(x_0) \over x-x_0} = a f'(x)$

Comment: Try a change of variables; instead of h, let , say $u=ah$ , change the limits , I think that should work.

Comment: So let $u=ah$ then $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0} {f(x_0 + u) - f(x_0) \over u} = \lim_{u\rightarrow 0} {f(x_0)+f(u) - f(x_0) \over u}$ then $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0} {f(u) \over u}$. then? Thanks for your hint tho!

Comment: Careful! , You cannot say that $f(x_0+u)=f(x_0)+f(u)$ unless you are given that $f$ is linear, or at least additive.

Comment: OK, would you give me more hints? I am trying to prove by the definition of differentiable function but still stuck.

Comment: Sure, give me a few seconds.

Comment: Basically, in your first comment, you did not change the variables correctly; see your denominator more carefully.

Comment: yeah I saw that my denominator changed from original $h$ to $ah$ and it should be $h$ as given in the question.

Comment: Yes, then $u=ah \rightarrow h=u/a....$.

Comment: Let me tackle it and I got stuck I'd ask you. Thanks for your hints so far!

Comment: Sure, go for it, if I cant reply today ( will have to go sleep), I will reply ASAP.

Comment: @PassingBy When you have a chance, please have a look my answer in question. Thanks a lot and have a good night!

Comment: Seems right, good job.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, because it's not clear what the question is at present.